# How do i upload and download pdf Documents from MongoDB without GridFS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, file-transfer

I'm trying to upload and download a file using a messaging api built using node.js and mongoDB. The message collection in the data base is defined as follows using mongoose.

```js
const chatMessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: {
      type: String,
      default: () => uuidv4().replace(/\-/g, ""),
    },
    chatRoomId: String,
    message: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: () => MESSAGE_TYPES.TYPE_TEXT,
    },
    postedByUser: String,
    readByRecipients: [readByRecipientSchema],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    collection: "chatmessages",
  }
);
```

I believe I can upload files into 'message' as it is a Mixed.Type. How would I go about doing so?

This is my post message function in the api

```js
postMessage: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const { roomId } = req.params;
            
            const validation = makeValidation(types => ({
                payload: req.body,
                checks: {
                    messageText: {type: types.string },
                }
            }));
            if (!validation.success) return res.status(400).json({...validation});
            
            const messagePayload = {
                messageText: req.body.messageText,
            };
            
            const currentLoggedUser = req.userId;
            const post = await ChatMessageModel.createPostInChatRoom(
                roomId,
                messagePayload,
                currentLoggedUser
            );
            

            // Send message through socket
            // global.IDBObjectStore.sockets.in(roomId).emit
            return res.status(200).json({ success: true, post });

        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                error: error
            })
        }
```

createPostInChat is as follows:

```js
/**
 * This method will create a post in chat
 * 
 * @param {String} roomId - id of chat room
 * @param {Object} message - message you want to post in the chat room
 * @param {String} postedByUser - user who is posting the message
 */
chatMessageSchema.statics.createPostInChatRoom = async function (chatRoomId, message, postedByUser) {
  try {
    console.log("chat message controller working");
    const post = await this.create({
      chatRoomId,
      message,
      postedByUser,
      readByRecipients: { readByUserId: postedByUser }
    });
    console.log(post);
    const aggregate = await this.aggregate([
      // get post where _id = post._id
      { $match: { _id: post._id } },
      // do a join on another table called users, and 
      // get me a user whose _id = postedByUser
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'postedByUser',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'postedByUser',
        }
      },
      { $unwind: '$postedByUser' },
      // do a join on another table called chatrooms, and 
      // get me a chatroom whose _id = chatRoomId
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'chatrooms',
          localField: 'chatRoomId',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'chatRoomInfo',
        }
      },
      { $unwind: '$chatRoomInfo' },
      { $unwind: '$chatRoomInfo.userIds' },
      // do a join on another table called users, and 
      // get me a user whose _id = userIds
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'chatRoomInfo.userIds',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'chatRoomInfo.userProfile',
        }
      },
      { $unwind: '$chatRoomInfo.userProfile' },
      // group data
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$chatRoomInfo._id',
          postId: { $last: '$_id' },
          chatRoomId: { $last: '$chatRoomInfo._id' },
          message: { $last: '$message' },
          type: { $last: '$type' },
          postedByUser: { $last: '$postedByUser' },
          readByRecipients: { $last: '$readByRecipients' },
          chatRoomInfo: { $addToSet: '$chatRoomInfo.userProfile' },
          createdAt: { $last: '$createdAt' },
          updatedAt: { $last: '$updatedAt' },
        }
      }
    ]);
    return aggregate[0];
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

How would i go about uploading pdfs using my api?